# QUAST and iCloud with spaces in Mobile Documents path

Tags: icloud

I am using quast to analyze some assemblies. My issue stems more from iCloud than it does quast. When giving quast inputs, it will not accepts spaces in the path. I have my data synced with iCloud, and so the path has this "Mobile Documents" directory that quast won't accept. So, I simply changed the directory name to "Mobile_Documents". Easy enough... I thought.
Somewhere, however, iCloud really wants this space in the specified directory, and so has remade the "Mobile Documents" directory and re-populated it with my files. So, I now have two similar directories "Mobile Documents" and "Mobile_Documents" which, is not only using up extra space, but also very confusing when I was working on a file and after saving it it wasn't in the directory I was expecting it to be... etc. 
Has anyone else had this issue? Is there a list or file somewhere that I can edit?
Thanks for your advice.
Best,
Rene

Comment: I also forgot to mention, that I ran Onyx between renaming "Mobile_Documents" and the newly created "Mobile Documents".

Comment: iCloud has both the old and new directories, which it sees as separate entities. Just delete the old version with a space.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating a "soft link" or alias to the "Mobile Documents" directory. This way I can specify the alias path when using QUAST.

```
$ln -s <source/real path> <destination/new link>
```